# How can I autosize textbox height in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Maybe someone can help me with the following problem. I want to adjust the height of a textbox control (asp.net) based on its content. The height must fith the content in the textbox no mather how long it is.

It should be possible to do it with javascript or just with C#. It should be simple but i cant get it done. Any help would appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: *It should be simple but i cant get it done.* Go to the person who told you that's simple and ask them to code it. Then  take a step back and enjoy.

Comment: Anything server-side won't take into account client settings (what font? do they use accessibility? are graphics absent giving you more real estate? etc.)

Comment: [how to set the height of textbox to AUTO](http://forums.asp.net/t/1263807.aspx?how+to+set+the+height+of+textbox+to+AUTO) is un VB example but is simple translate in c#

Comment: I think you can set height to auto by jquery . That will solve the problem .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a jquery library already made for that, you can find it here: http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/ and it is fairly easy to get started with.

Just follow his example code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('textarea').autosize();   
});
```

Comment: @BradChristie there i formulated it as an answer.